# Horizontal ScrollView inside Vertical

Tags: react-native, scrollview

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l7VUX.jpg)The structure of my code looks like the following:

```
<View style={{backgroundColor:'#FFF',flex:1,}}>
<ScrollView 
  showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false}
  contentContainerStyle={{paddingBottom:120}} stickyHeaderIndices={[6]}
>
...some content...
<ScrollView horizontal showsHorizontalScrollIndicator={false}
   bounces={false}
   scrollEventThrottle={16}
   pagingEnabled={...}
   decelerationRate={...}
   snapToInterval={...}
   disableIntervalMomentum={true}
   snapToAlignment={"center"}
   snapToOffsets={screens}
   contentContainerStyle={{flexGrow:1}}
>
  {horizontalContent}
</ScrollView>
</ScrollView>
```

but the content inside the horizontal scroll has different heights and all items become the same height as the largest, which creates a huge scroll space. How can fix this? Help pls

Comment: i cant understand clearly whats problem here, problem with height `scrollview horizontal` or something else? can you edit and gimme a bit screenshot ?

Comment: @Edofx Yes, problem with height horizontal items. They have different heights and each item gets value of highest item. Added an image

Answer (score 0):

If you can see in my [sample](https://snack.expo.dev/@m.bahl/specific-element-height)

Pink, red and blue bar have a specific height, they don’t grow to the containers max.

The turkey bar has a `flex:1` which cause the container grow to the max, to prevent this behavior you could wrap the elements container with an view and pass the `flex:0` style as i did for the black bar.

Comment: This solution is suitable when the height of the elements is known in advance. For me, it will change every time, because the content will be taken from the server

Comment: What happen when you wrap each element in a view with flex:0, or pass direct to each element flex:0?

Comment: items take the correct height, but the vertical scroll still goes down